# When updating and downloading packages what has the absolute freshest packages, the US server or the Main?

Tags: updates, 13.04

When selecting the server to download packages from in "Software & Updates" I have a choice between the US server and Main server, which would be updated first and therefore have the absolute freshest packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USA has [69 mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) for Ubuntu. Some of them are uptodate, other a little behind the main one.

Anyway, the main server in England is considered the most uptodate.